# Select rows with same column A but different column B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ID          Zip        Room
----------- ---------- ------
317         94087      S105
318         94087      L603
1739        94404-1801 L603
1823        94401-2129 L603
1824        94401-2129 L603
2135        94404-1801 L603
2268        95136-1459 S604
2269        95136-1459 S604
3704        92673-6417 L402
4479        93454-9670 L402
4480        93454-9670 L402
4782        92395-4681 L402
4783        92395-4681 L402
4852        92886-4411 L402
4853        92886-4411 L402
4959        92673-6417 L402
5153        91773-4028 L402
5202        91773-4028 L402
5211        91765-2959 L402
5212        91765-2959 L402
5388        92336-0605 L402
5392        92336-0605 L402
5727        92870      L402
5728        92870      L402
5831        92557      L402
5916        92557      L402
```

How do I select ID's that has THE SAME zip but different Room ?

In the table above, I want the result to be:

```
ID          Zip        Room
----------- ---------- ------
317         94087      S105
318         94087      L603
```

Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
SELECT ID, Zip, Room 
FROM dbo.Table t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table t2
   WHERE t2.Zip = t1.Zip
   AND t2.Room <> t1.Room
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select * 
from table t1 
join table t2 
  on t1.Zip = t2.Zip and t1.Room <> t2.Room
```

Comment: Can you add t1.* or t2.* in select

Answer (score 0):

You could use the window aggregate functions `MIN()` and `MAX()` to get, correspondingly, the minimum and the maximum `Room` per `Zip`, then select only the rows where those values differ. Here:

```
WITH MinMax AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    MinRoom = MIN(Room) OVER (PARTITION BY Zip),
    MaxRoom = MAX(Room) OVER (PARTITION BY Zip)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Zip,
  Room
FROM MinMax
WHERE MinRoom <> MaxRoom
;
```