# How do I find the name of soccer players with same first name but different surnames?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, inner-join

I need to find the names of players from soccer team A that have the same first name but different surname as players from soccer team B. I need to produce the full names of all players from Team A, not just 'John'. I am able to use an additional column with Player IDs unique across all teams.

Basically table looks like this:

```
FirstName  LastName     Team
John       Snow         A
Batman     Dies         B
John       Dies         B
```

I can produce a list of Team A names with the same first name as Team B players.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table
```

Even though surname can't be used for one entry, it should be considered for other entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows with same column A but different column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093642/select-rows-with-same-column-a-but-different-column-b)

Comment: That codes obviously does not "produce a list of Team A names with the same first name as Team B players". Why do you say it does? Your code returns rows where player [firstname] [lastname] is on some team. PS Your last sentence is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. (Click on 'edited ...' to see how your post has been edited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select distinct t1.FirstName
from
(
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM @t where Team = 'A'
) as t1
inner join
(
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM @t where Team = 'B'
) as t2
on (t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName)
where t1.LastName <> t2.LastName
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create duplicates of the same player if there were more than one 'John' in team B?

Comment: @CampionCircle yes it would. It should have the distinct.

Comment: I should have specified, I am required to produce full team A names.

Comment: @CampionCircle What you want to get is the name of players in team A that are in team B with same name and different surname?

Comment: Yes. I added IDs to the players, changed your first line to 'select distinct t1.ID' and enclosed that to state 'select FirstName, LastName FROM table where ID in (...)

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM Table A
INNER JOIN Table B
ON A.FirstName = B.FirstName AND A.LastName <> B.LastName 
WHERE A.Team = 'A' AND B.Team = 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common table expression and then do an inner join on the firstname. In the below example I've split the teams using the CTE and then joined back on ensuring the teams don't match, the last name doesn't match and the first name does match.

I've then used a union statement to show how the player in the other team can be shown as well.

```
declare @soccerteam table
(
    FirstName nvarchar(50),
    LastName nvarchar(50),
    Team nvarchar(3)
);

insert @soccerteam (FirstName, LastName, Team)
values
('John',       'Snow',         'A'),
('Batman',     'Dies',         'B'),
('John',       'Dies',         'B');

select * from @soccerteam;

with teamB as (select FirstName, LastName, Team from @soccerteam where Team='B')

select 'Players in Team A matching Team B', a.* from @soccerteam a inner join teamB b on a.FirstName=b.FirstName and a.LastName<>b.LastName and a.Team<>b.Team
union
select 'Players in Team B matching Team A', b.* from @soccerteam a inner join teamB b on a.FirstName=b.FirstName and a.LastName<>b.LastName and a.Team<>b.Team;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Table 
  WHERE Team = 'A'
),CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Table
  WHERE Team = 'B'
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE R1
JOIN CTE1 R2 ON R1.FirstName = R2.FirstName
             AND R1.LastName <> R2.LastName
```